# how do i pass optional parameter to the __init__ function in python class

Tags: python

I have a class that takes 3 parameters(2 compulsory and 1 optional).
This is the part of my code:

```
def __init__(self, user, url, env=None):
    """init method for the class."""
    self.user = user
    self.url = url
    if env is None:
        self.env = ""
    else:
        self.env = env

def check_file(self):
    # get the env value from a dictionary
    if self.env == "test":
        self.address = value['key1']
    else:
        self.address = value['key2']
```

The `address` variable has 2 values, one for production env and one for test env. If this `env` variable is passed as `p` then the value of `self.address` should be production url address and if the `env` value is `t` then the `self.address` shpuld be test url address , but if the `env` value is not passed then the `self.address` value should be the `key3` value from the dictionary `value`. These production url address and test url address are the `key1` and `key2` of the dictionary `value`

I came up with this code, but this seems to be not working.

Comment: What error message do you get? You have a strange condition `if envType is None:` That should of course be `if env is None:`

Comment: Don’t use ˋdict` as a variable. It is a builtin function. Choose a different name.

Comment: Why not `..., env=''):` ?

Comment: edited the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
def __init__(self, user, url, env=None):
    """init method for the class."""
    self.user = user
    self.url = url
    if env is None:
        self.env = ""
    else:
        self.env = env

def check_file(self):
    # get the env value from a dictionary
    if self.env: # if not an empty string
        if self.env == "test":
            self.address = value['key1']
        else:
            self.address = value['key2']
    else:
        self.address = value['key3']
```